# How to use custom font in asp.net website?

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts

I am creating an asp.net website in which I want to set the font of a label.I am trying to do this through CSS.The font that I need to apply is Shivaji05, which would not be available on most systems.This is the CSS:

```
body 
{    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Shivaji05"; 
    src:url("/Shivaji05.eot");
    src:url("/Shivaji05.woff")format("woff");
    src:url("/Shivaji05.ttf")format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


.txtQues
{
    font-family: "Shivaji05";    
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:White;
}
```

The source:

```
<head>    
<link href="../FontSettings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>

<asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" runat="server" Text="Type Your Question Here" 
Font-Bold="True" EnableTheming="False" CssClass="txtQues"></asp:Label>
```

But this does not work, is there any mistake in this?how should I get this working?Kindly suggest if there are any other alternatives to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below code. In addition; custom font will render in every browser once define the font MIME type as well in config file or in IIS setting.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shivaji05';
  src: url('Shivaji05.eot'); 
  src: url('Shivaji05.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('Shivaji05.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('Shivaji05.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('Shivaji05.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); 
}
```

> **Note:** All latest browser have support for font type `woff`.

**Update**

see attached image. Define MIME Type for font format `.woff` the MIME type will be `application/x-font-woff` 
[image]

Comment: make sure to upload the font on server and then give a font path in CSS file.

Comment: not yet,I haven't done it before,can you give me a few links so that I can understand how I can upload a font on the server. @Kheema Pandey

Comment: Normally as you upload the `.aspx file`, `CSS` or `images` on server.

Comment: Can I test it on my local computer and in that case how should I go about it. @Kheema Pandey

Comment: let me make a example